# How can i obtain a tsibble from this tibble without using the as.Date function?

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate, tsibble

I need to convert several "tibble" into "tsibble".

Here a simple example:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)

time_1 <- c(ymd_hms('20210101 000000'),
            ymd_hms('20210101 080000'),
            ymd_hms('20210101 160000'),
            # ymd_hms('20210102 000000'),
            ymd_hms('20210102 080000'),
            ymd_hms('20210102 160000'))

df_1 <- tibble(time_1, y=rnorm(5))

df_1 %>% 
  as_tsibble(index=time_1)
```

This chunk of code works as expected.
But, if the dates are all midnights, this code throws an error:

```
time_2 <- c(ymd_hms('20210101 000000'),
            ymd_hms('20210102 000000'),
            ymd_hms('20210103 000000'),
            # ymd_hms('20210104 000000'),
            ymd_hms('20210105 000000'),
            ymd_hms('20210106 000000'))

df_2 <- tibble(time_2, y=rnorm(5))

df_2 %>% 
  as_tsibble(index=time_2)
```

I don't want to solve this issue in this way because the `as.Date` function changes the column type.

```
df_2 %>% 
  mutate(time_2=as.Date(time_2)) %>% 
  as_tsibble(index=time_2)
```

I also don't want to fix the issue in this way because after converting the tibble into tsibble i need to apply the `fill_gaps` function, which doesn't create the `ymd_hms('20210104 000000')` in this second scenario.

```
df_2 %>% 
  as_tsibble(index=time_2, regular=FALSE)
```

Is this a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: This does seem a bit odd. it might be worth posting as in issue on their [github issues page](https://github.com/tidyverts/tsibble/issues)

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is explained in tsibble's [FAQ](https://tsibble.tidyverts.org/articles/faq.html).

Essentially subdaily data (`ymd_hms()`) measured at midnight each day doesn't necessarily have an interval of 1 day (24 hours). Consider that some days have shifts due to daylight savings in your time zone, and so the number of hours between midnight and midnight the next day may be 23 or 25 hours.

If you're working with data measured at a daily interval, you should use a date with `ymd()` precision. You can covert it back to a date time using `as_datetime()` if you like.

Personally I don't think this should produce an error, however it is much simpler if it does. Perhaps the appropriate interval here is 1 hour or 30 minutes (or whatever is appropriate for timezone shifts in the specified timezone).

Comment: Thanks for your preciuos comment. When you say "Essentially sub-daily data (ymd_hms()) measured at midnight each day doesn't necessarily have an interval of 1 day (24 hours)." I totally agree with you.
But this problem also affects the time series measured every 8 hours, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sub-daily data with an 8 hour interval with daylight savings changes will not always have an 8 hour gap, so the precise interval would be more like 1 hour. If you wanted to have an 8 hour interval and ignore daylight savings changes you can use a timezone that does not have daylight savings.

Comment: In the example I reported I get an 8 hour interval correctly (df_1), and that's what I expect. The problem that has made me the question is that with intervals at midnight the code goes into error. And the reasons why it fails should also fail for the dataset with the 8 hour interval.

Comment: Yes. The error you get for your midnight interval is not necessarily needed, but is raised to prevent common mistakes that people make when not considering timezones. Perhaps it is better to give a warning here instead.

You get your desired 8 hour interval here because the range of data you are using does not contain a shift in time due to the timezone.